# What anesthesia should I request for my mole removal as a vegan?

Tags: veganism, medicine

I'm planning to get a mole removed from my face. I'm vegan, and I would like my dermatologist to use anesthesia that doesn't contain any animal products. I know in the US all medicine is tested on animals and is therefore never cruelty free, but I just want to find the best option out there. **For mole removal, what is a good, vegan anesthesia option?** Options to consider: Lignocaine, Bupivacaine, Ropivacaine.

Comment: Have you asked the dermatologist what anaesthetics they have available?

Answer (score 1):

Cryotherapy (liquid nitrogen treatment) does not require any anesthetic. Depending on the skin condition, your doctor may decide to apply this removal method.

Before freezing the mole off, your doctor will evaluate how vascularized it is and may perform tests to determine if it is malignant.

You will experience some stinging and some level of pain during the procedure and a few minutes after the treatment, but not at a level requiring anesthetic.